# Fetch last item in a category that fits specific criteria

Tags: sql, mysql, join

Let's assume I have a database with two tables: `categories` and `articles`. Every article belongs to a category.

Now, let's assume I want to fetch the latest article of each category that fits a specific criteria (read: the article does). If it weren't for that extra criteria, I could just add a column called `last_article_id` or something similar to the `categories` table - even though that wouldn't be properly normalized.

How can I do this though? I assume there's something using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`?

Comment: Is there no way without subqueries?

Comment: See http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/

Comment: @chris: That looks very nice.

Comment: I should add that the other answers look very good, too. This is just very in-depth, too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM categories AS c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC) AS a
       ON c.id = a.id_category
      AND /criterias about joining/
    WHERE /more criterias/
 GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: This came closest to my solution, except that I added some filters in the subquery, too (when they were referring to articles).

Answer (score 0):

If you provide us with the Tables schemas, we could be a little more specific, but you could try something like ([12.2.9.6. EXISTS and NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), [SELECT Syntax for LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html))

```
SELECT  *
FROM    articles a
WHERE   EXISTS  (   
                    SELECT  1 
                    FROM    articles 
                    where   category_id = a.category_id
                    AND     <YourCriteria Here>
                    ORDER BY    <Order Required : ID DESC, LastDate DESC or something?
                    LIMIT 1
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the id's in the articles table represent always increasing numbers, this should work.  Using the id is not semantically correct IMHO, you should actually use a time/date tamp field if one is available.

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id IN
  (
    SELECT 
      MAX(article_id) 
    FROM
      articles 
    WHERE [your filters here]
    GROUP BY 
      category_id
  )
```